# C# Circular dependencies in Unity with Ctor injection

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism, circular-dependency

I know that the issue of circular dependencies in the contect of dependency injection with prism/unity was dicussed here before.

But I still don't get it. Suppose the following classes:

```
class Feeder : IFeeder    { 
  IManager _MM, 
  Feeder(IManager MM)
  {
     this._MM = MM;
  }
  public void Start()
  {
  ...
  }
  public void Stop()
  {
  ...
  }
  private Propagate()
  {
     _MM.ConsumeFeed()
  }
};

class FeedManager : IManager
{
   IFeeder _Feeder;
   FeedManager(IFeeder Feeder)
   {
      this._Feeder = Feeder;
   }
   public ConsumeFeed()
   {
   ...
   }
   private Shutdown()
   {
      _Feeder.Stop();
   }
   private StartUp()
   {
      _Feeder.Start();
   }
};
```

This is clearly a circular dependcy, since Feeder depends on FeedManager and vice verca. I don't see a clear way to resovle this, since it seems a very natural design.

When you follow this [link](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/) there is a hint to extract some methods but I still don't see how I can decouple those objects.
I read about dependency inversion, observer pattern, shared objects, events and so on.
To me, this seems all like an overkill to achieve a simple realtionship between the two objects.

Is the only way to resolve this to work with a million events in the application or shared objects?
Thanks for help, Juergen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the IFeeder.Propagate method an event the instance of IManager registers to. This way you do not have a circular reference.

Your example here has by the way nothing to do with unity. From my point of view it is more a design issue than an unity issue.

Comment: Yes, its a design issue. The thing is, that unity uses Ctor injection and its poissible to overcome this with propery injection(a delayed instantiation mechanism). So in general, to avoid this is using events. But as I said I want to avoid having a million events in the app.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid events? From my point of view there is no reason to avoid events.

Comment: Suppose that FeedManager raises also an event which should be consumed by Feeder. Then again there is the cyclic dependency. In this case, would an eventaggregator be the solution?

Comment: Then you have made the same mistake. Objects usually have a hierarchy. One is the parent, one is the child. The parent calls the child, but the child never calls the parent. If the parent is interested in things that happen to the child object, it has to register to events that indicate those happenings. Please don't get me wrong but I feel that you should have a look at some OOP basics first.